# 'elseif' or 'else if' in Fortran

Tags: syntax, fortran

Is there any difference between `elseif` and `else if` in Fortran? Same goes for `endif` and `end if` or `enddo` and `end do`.

I found both options in a code I am working on and wondered if it makes any difference in Fortran; furthermore if one option is preferable over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Fortran language there is no difference in meaning/syntax. `else` and `if` are keywords and in fixed-form source blanks are between keywords are insignificant; in free-form source blanks are significant in general and should be used to separate keywords except in a given list of adjoining keywords.

`else if`, `end if`, and `end do` are pairs where blanks are optional. The entire list is given in Table 6.2 of the current Fortran standard. `end` features in most but also notable are `double precision`, `else where`, `go to`, `in out`, and `select case`.

Local style guides may state a preference.

---

<sub>**source: [Fortran 2018 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)**</sub>

[image: Copy of Table 6.2]